# how to open .bin file using terminal in linux

Tags: linux

I have one .bin file.in that file some data which is important for me and and i want to open that file by using terminal so please help me.I have not any software for that. so give me and command.

Comment: file yourfile.bin to get the filetype. What is actually in the file?

Comment: `.bin` files or `.run` files are usually, in my experience, self extracting shell scripts. Where did you get this from? What's the name? What is it supposed to contain?

Comment: do you want to open (read) it or run it? call ``file my.bin``, see if its a shell script and then run it with ``sh my.bin``. i hope the source of the file is trustworthy!

Answer (score 6):

You have to be sure of what you're downloading (because a `.bin` file extension is also used for CD/DVD images and backups). Check with the "provider" (Web Page, CD/DVD instructions, etc...) of the file that it can be executed as a program.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_file):

> A binary file is a computer file that is not a text file. The term
>   "binary file" is often used as a term meaning "non-text file". Many
>   binary file formats contain parts that can be interpreted as text; for
>   example, some computer document files containing formatted text, such
>   as older Microsoft Word document files, contain the text of the
>   document but also contain formatting information in binary form.

[If your .bin file is an installer/executable](https://askubuntu.com/questions/156392/what-is-the-equivalent-of-an-exe-file#174356), then follow these steps:

1. Open your terminal and go to `~$ cd /Downloads` (where `~/Downloads` is the folder where you bin file is)
2. Give it execution permissions (just in case it doesn't have it already): 
    
    `~/Downloads$ sudo chmod +x filename.bin`
3. Write: `./` followed by the name and extension of your bin file. In this example it would be:
   `~/Downloads$ ./filename.bin`

Note:

- If `filename.bin` needs administrator priviledges to be executed (like an installer would), write `~/Downloads$ sudo ./filename.bin` and type your password.
- `~/Downloads` folder is only an example. You can place your bin file anywhere you feel comfortable (yes, even a USB Drive or a SDCard).

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
sudo vim <filename>
```

or if you don't like vim:

```
open -a "<texteditor>" <filename>
```

where `<texteditor>` is your text editor and `<filename>` is the file name

Remember to navigate to the folder first

Answer (score 0):

to be honest i've got the same issue many many times i've downloaded some files.bin , however the only best solution that i've done is to extract the file.bin from windows vmware , you just need to set the share network from windows vmware to linux machine and extract it with winearchiver software to linux as you are connect to the share folder , even if you use chmod 755 file.bin and then ./file.bin , it won't works generally speaking , i am talking as linux user and not windows user , however in some cases combine the solution with windows vmware in order to solve quickly the problem rather than rubbish solutions that won't work .

Answer (score -1):

6 years later. I hope it'll be useful.

`losetup -f --show "/path/to/filename.bin"
LOOP=$$(losetup | grep "filename.bin" | cut -d ' ' -f1)
kpartx -l $LOOP | cut -d ' ' -f1                    
mount -v /dev/mapper/loop0p1 /mnt/`

Comment: Mind explaining what this is doing?

Answer (score -3):

your question is very nice and you can open .bin file easily using terminal,........
so please follow this command

1. first login as root user using:

   ```
   sudo su
   ```
2. after that go upto dir in which your .bin file for that use:

   ```
   cd /yourdir
   ```
3. after reach upto your .bin file use this command:

   ```
   gksudo gedit filename.bin
   ```

Comment: -1. This is not a useful answer. `sudo su` is unnecessary. The `gksudo` assumes a gnome/gtk based desktop and is also unnecessary and finally, it shows a way to edit rather than "open" (which usually means run). the file.

Comment: too much root!  the same can be done with ``less`` (pun intended)